# Is it possible to download a big folder or games using Python 3?

Tags: file, download, urllib, python-3.6

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(link_of_file, file_name)
```

As the line above is for downloading a single file
What about downloading a big folder or a game?

Comment: What is a *game* for you? A single file? A folder? An archive? An executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is not designed to download folders. You can only get single files resources. I think that there's no limit to the file size.